# Android. Controlling zooming speed

Tags: android, scale

I'm creating `View` that can store, move, zoom and crop a picture. I'm aware about many projects which already done this, so link to other project wouldn't be answer, but i'm not sure that it's possible to achive my request.

So basically i'm using `ScaleGestureDetector` with `ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener`, to scale my `Canvas`, here's a code:

```
private float MIN_SCALE_FACTOR = 0.3f;
private float MAX_SCALE_FACTOR = 10.0f;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
private ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener mScaleListener = new ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE_FACTOR, Math.min(mScaleFactor, MAX_SCALE_FACTOR));
        invalidate();
        return super.onScale(detector);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mBitmap != null) {
        canvas.save();
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        correctPositionValues();
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mPositionX, mPositionY );
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mPositionX, mPositionY, null);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

On my phone scale is happening almoust instantly and this looks bad.
Any suggestions highly appreciated

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but try `mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();` instead of `*=`

Comment: @Joakim, there is one minus with this approach. Whenever i'm using scroll again it will scale picture to 1.f even if it's 0.3f currently

Comment: Yes. I'm not awake yet.

Comment: You could implement some kind of queue, receiving factor from gestures and calling ui changing code with some delayed or even normalized values

Answer (score 0):

Scale on the previous scale factor:

```
private ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener mScaleListener = new ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
    private preScaleFactor = 1f;
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor = preScaleFactor*detector.getScaleFactor();
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE_FACTOR, Math.min(mScaleFactor, MAX_SCALE_FACTOR));
        invalidate();
        return super.onScale(detector);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
       preScaleFactor = mScaleFactor;
       return true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin:

```
class GestureScaleListener : ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
        var multiplierScaleFactor = 0.05f
        var scaleFactor = 1f

        override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector?): Boolean {
            val detectorScale = (detector?.scaleFactor ?: 1f)
            val realScale = detectorScale - 1f

            scaleFactor = (multiplierScaleFactor * realScale) + 1

            return super.onScale(detector)
        }
    }
```

For the first, need to calculate the difference between `detectorScale` and `1f` (default scale). After that use `multiplierScaleFactor` (change it for your issue) value for reduce zoom speed/sensivity and return `1f` (default scale) to the back.